# Importing PHP Array into Bootstrap Cards

Tags: php

I have some JSON, $json.
This is parsed with json_decode to give me an array of which I can extract values. For each item in this array, how can I move it's values into a bootstrap card?

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode($content, true);
    foreach($json['response']['results'] as $response){
        echo $response['fields']['headline'] . "<br/>";
        echo $response['fields']['trailText'] . "<br/>";
        echo $response['fields']['thumbnail'] . "<br/>";
        echo $response['fields']['shortUrl'] . "<br/></br>";
    }
?>
```

An example bootstrap card:

```
<div class="card" style="max-width:319px;">
    <img src="myImage.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
        <a href="http://website.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need a loop. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. Inside the loop, output your HTML with variables in place.

Comment: Do you want to use theme logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo your html inside the foreach loop and add the fields values

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode($content, true);
    foreach($json['response']['results'] as $response){
        echo '<div class="card" style="max-width:319px;">
            <img src="' . $response['fields']['thumbnail'] . '" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">' . $response['fields']['headline'] . '</h4>
                <p class="card-text">' . $response['fields']['trailText'] . '</p>
                <a href="' . $response['fields']['shortUrl'] . '" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
            </div>
        </div>; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do something like this:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($content, true);
foreach($json['response']['results'] as $response){
    ?>
    <div class="card" style="max-width:319px;">
        <img src="<?=$response['fields']['thumbnail']?>" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title"><?=$response['fields']['headline']?></h4>
            <p class="card-text"><?=$response['fields']['trailText']?></p>
            <a href="<?=$response['fields']['shortUrl']?>" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <?php
}
?>
```

I thinks is better for changes, Let me know if this works for you!